# Adding Adwords remarketing tag/code in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, google-ads-api

Here's the code Adwords tells me to add "before the `</body>` tag:

```
<!-- Google Code for Remarketing Tag -->
<!--------------------------------------------------
Remarketing tags may not be associated with personally identifiable information or placed on pages related to sensitive categories. See more information and instructions on how to setup the tag on: http://google.com/ads/remarketingsetup
--------------------------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 000; //changed the code
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/000/?guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Well, as I'm working with React (in Meteor) I don't really have access to any `<body>` tags and this is not how I add scripts. Besides, I'd like to try to make this async if I can.

My first instinct was to add a component and cram it into `base_layout.jsx` (which is what gets mounted on all routes):

```
const TagManager = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount() {
        const conversionSrc = "//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"
        const remarketingSrc = "//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/000/?guid=ON&amp;script=0"

        var google_conversion_id = 000;
        var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
        var google_remarketing_only = true;

        //Here I am lost what to do next
    },

    render() {
        //Do I even need a render?
    }
})
```

Some problems:

1) I don't know what two different externals scripts do and how I should execute them.

2) I've read somewhere that there is an async alternative but I can't find it or figure out how to use it.

3) I'd like to do everything in `componentDidMount` but I don't know what the deal is with the image.

Also, wouldn't it be better to run the first script, get back the text file, and paste that instead of relying on some external script?

What do I do?

Comment: you have a single base html file something like main.html with a body and an empty div to mount your app, just put it there

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak That would mean I put it in `<head>`. I have no `<body>` anywhere.

Comment: why? Your main.html file should have a body, if it doesn't you're doing something wrong. You could put it anywhere you wanted. You could put it after your render target. Regardless then it will be on every page. If you really need to do this with JS then use vanilla js. get your render target dom node and then give it siblings. You can create script tags and set their sources dynamically - something like this: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Gobbledigook.

Comment: post your main.html file, it makes no sense that you wouldn't have a render target

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak `<head><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no"></head>`

Comment: have you even run your app? where are you mounting it?

Comment: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak lol yes it's deployed and running. You're focusing on the wrong thing. I'm using FlowRouter.